# UILabel shows wrong Localized String

Tags: ios, swift, localization, xcode9-beta

I have a problem with localizing a string through the Localizable.stringdict. I did setup different localization for different sizes of a Test string. See Localizable.stringdict:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Test</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSStringVariableWidthRuleType</key>
        <dict>
            <key>20</key>
            <string>test</string>
            <key>25</key>
            <string>test message</string>
            <key>50</key>
            <string>This is a test message</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My ViewController looks like the following:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        let string = NSLocalizedString("Test", comment: "This is a test message") as NSString
        let widthFormattedString = string.variantFittingPresentationWidth(50) as String

        print(widthFormattedString)
        label.text = widthFormattedString
    }

    override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()

    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

I would like to assign the localized string to a label. The print in my ViewController is printing "This is a test message", but the view is showing "test message". I don't change the text of the label anywhere else. So I wonder why the wrong message is displayed. Can anyone help?

Comment: Localizable.stringdict : are you talking about localizable.strings file?

Comment: No there is a localizable.stringdict file where you can specify different texts for different sizes

Comment: You have stated that 'The print in my ViewController is printing "This is a test message", but the view is showing "test message" ', but it will print only "Test" as it is Key.

Comment: No it is not just printing the key. It is using the Localizable.stringdict but however it is printing the value of the key 25 and not 50 as requested.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1413104-variantfittingpresentationwidth?language=objc) at writing this answer it states that:

> Note
>
> Don't call this method when setting user-visible text for standard UIKit controls, such as **UILabel**. UIKit provides built-in support for adaptive strings, and automatically selects the string width variant appropriate for the current screen size according to the behavior described below.

which seems to confirm what you experience.

The print out you do yourself is correct because it delivers you the string you requested for the value `50`:

> The print in my ViewController is printing "This is a test message"

Whereas the UILabel gets a the string by the UIKit standard mechanism and appears as:

> but the view is showing "test message"

I conclude that you don't need to do it yourself if you use UIKit controls. This is probably helpful for custom controls or other use cases I'm not aware of.